# pyqtgraph, how track log/linear axes transformation changes between linked axes

Tags: pyqtgraph

I have 3 linked views, linked by X axis.  This works great.  However, when I switch one plot to log X mode, the others do not switch to log x mode, but they pop in to zoom way in to the log version of the x axis.

How do it make it so the log X transformation applies to all plots?
So far, I simply use the code

```
diViewWidget.setXLink(frViewWidget)
noiseViewWidget.setXLink(diViewWidget)
```

The data should look like this:

[image]

but actually look like this:

[image]

Basically, to reproduce you can go to any 2 linked views, right click and set the transformation to log x.

The workaround I found is to go to each plot individually and set the transformation individually, but I'd like it to happen programatically.

Thanks,

-Caleb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#learning qt i just found a better linkLogXChecks version

from itertools import permutations
def linkLogXChecks(plotitems):
    for a, b in permutations(plotitems, 2):
        a.ctrl.logXCheck.toggled.connect(b.ctrl.logXCheck.setChecked)
```

Comment: clever.  I didn't know about itertools.

Answer (score 1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/3686qqVHgpI/bmBAQ_sDKJIJ
https://forum.qt.io/topic/39241/how-to-set-logarithmic-scale-on-a-qgraphicsview/2 
I couldn't apply that fix across separate PlotItems, so tried broadcasting the changed checkbox signal and it seems to work

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

data = pg.np.random.normal(size=100)

app = pg.QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
p1 = win.addPlot(y=data)

win.nextRow()
p2 = win.addPlot(y=data)
p2.setXLink(p1)

win.nextRow()
p3 = win.addPlot(y=data)
p3.setXLink(p1)


def linkLogXChecks(plotitems):
    def broadcast(state):
        for p in plotitems:
            p.ctrl.logXCheck.setChecked(state)
    for p in plotitems:
        p.ctrl.logXCheck.toggled.connect(broadcast)

linkLogXChecks([p1, p2, p3])


pg.QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```